# How to do Spotlight search in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, spotlight

I want to do Spotlight search in my iPhone application for applications. So I can get the particular application position in my iPhone. On which page and which row and column no application exist.

Please suggest how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your app only knows about itself.